# Are Weyl sequences polynomially bounded?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, sp.spectral-theory, schrodinger-operators

Look at the Hilbert space $l^2( \mathbb{Z}) $ and let $A$ be a translation invariant band operator. I.e. if $\{ e_n \}_{n \in \mathbb Z} $ is the standard basis for $l^2( \mathbb{Z}) $ then it holds that
\begin{align*}
\langle e_n, A e_m \rangle  = 0
\end{align*}
for $\vert n-m \vert \geq K$ for some $K$. And translation invariance gives
\begin{align*}
\langle e_n, A e_m \rangle  = \langle e_{n+k}, A e_{m+k} \rangle 
\end{align*}
for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

The eigenvalue equation reads

\begin{align*}
A \psi = \lambda \psi 
\end{align*}

for some function $\psi \in l^2 ( \mathbb{Z}) $.

Since $A$ is a band matrix we could extend this equation for functions $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}$ which we do not require to be square-summable and ask for solutions to this equation.

Is it now true that $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$ if and only if there exists such a solution $\psi$ which is bounded by a polynomial?
Maybe one needs to assume translation invariance.

Example: For the discrete Laplacian
\begin{align*}
\langle e_n, A e_m \rangle  = -2 \delta_{n,m} + \delta_{n+1,m} + \delta_{n,m+1} 
\end{align*}
we get solutions of the form $\psi(x) =e^{ipx}$ which are not square integrable, but are still solutions of the finite difference equation.
Notice that one can truncate these to construct af Weyl-sequence and it seems that this could prove at least one direction of the question.

The issue is discussed in chapter 7.1 https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.3707.pdf here for Hamiltonians $A$, but I am particularly interested in the non-normal case.

EDIT: (Partially progress using translation invariance)
By translation invariance the eigenvalue equation can be written as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = - K}^K a_i \psi_{i+n} = \lambda \psi_n 
\end{align*}
which is just linear recursion. So one can find the solutions using the characteristic equation and then they are either constant or exponentially increasing/decreasing. How can we show that the exponentially increasing solutions do not correspond to elements in the spectrum of $A$?
Edit2: In this case we can prove the result using Fourier Transformation, but what if the operator is not translation invariant, but translation invariant plus a compact pertubation?

Comment: Do you assume that $A$ is bounded?

Comment: Yes, $A$ is bounded.

Comment: Assume that $A$ is purely diagonal. Then the spectrum is the closure of the set of diagonal entries, but there is no chance to create the corresponding "eigenvector" (polynomially bounded or not) unless $\lambda$ is appearing on the diagonal. So, we may have at most one-directional statement here.

Comment: Thank you, I see that I somehow miss the point here. In your example if there is a sequence $\lambda_n$ of diagonal entries converging to $\lambda$ then a Weyl sequence would be the eigenvectors with a one in that diagonal entry. It is polynomially bounded, but of course this is not what I ask. Maybe I do not some translation invariance. Let met think.

Comment: One could worry whether your counterexample contradicts "chapter 7.1 https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.3707.pdf " since it is indeed within the setup he discusses. But he has this loopwhole that it is up to a set of spectral measure 0. The spectral measure however is not defined for non-normal operators. So in order to obtain a general statement one would need an appropriate notion of "up to a set of spectral measure 0".

Comment: But I actually only care about the (almost) translation invariant case. So I'll reformulate the question to this case.

Comment: "How can we show that the exponentially increasing solutions do not correspond to elements in the spectrum of A?" It is a convolution operator now, so just pass to the Fourier side ;-)

Comment: Yes, I agree that in the translation invariant case one can also do a proof using that the spectrum of a multiplication operator is the range of the function.

Comment: However, this does not resolve my trouble. I think one can take some condition which excludes your case (and which is like the spectral measure 0 condition in the self-adjoint). In particular I'd like to consider translation invariant operator + compact pertubation and showing that the compact pertubation only is able to give extra spectrum if the corresponding solution to the recursion is polynomially bounded (actually bounded by a constant, since one can consider the same recursion with different initial conditions).

Comment: I think that one can use the fact that all "potential approximate eigenvectors" are exponentially increasing to prove that $\vert \vert (A+K - \lambda)v \vert \vert  \geq \vert \vert v \vert \vert$ for all $v$  where $A$ is invertible and $K$ is some compact pertubation.

Comment: Ah, but it is a completely different question from what you formally requested (and a more interesting one). OK, I'll think of that. Just to clarify: (i) Is $A+K$ also band-limited? (ii) potential approximate eigenvectors of $A$ or $A+K$?

Comment: Yes, we could just say that $K$ is a finite rank matrix with the same bands as $A$ but instead of being infinite in both directions it is only affects a few of the terms in the recursion (meaning that the recursion is exactly the same outside some small interval around zero).  Ad ii) Yes potential approximate eigenvectors of $A+K$. Then we can still see that all solutions to this recursion will be either exponentially decreasing, constant or exponentially increasing.

Comment: The trouble we have to address however is that you could have a sequence $\psi_n$ which only nearly solves the systems of equation (as in your example with the diagonal) and then one still needs to prove that $ \vert \vert (A+K - \lambda) \psi  \vert \vert $ is large

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric and, say, $0$ is an eigenvalue of both $A$ and $A+K$ (otherwise the Fredholm theory gives the result in no time), then the space of slowly growing at $-\infty$ eigen-sequences has dimension greater than half the recursion length, so once you pass this space through the perturbation, it intersects the space of slowly growing sequences at $+\infty$ non-trivially, thus giving you the desired sequence.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the Fredholm theory tells you that you can't loose any eigenvalues. But you could potential get some extra ones.

Comment: Those have true eigenvectors!

Comment: Really? The argument is not quite clear to me. If we assume that the recursion length is 2. Then why would the space of slowly growing (meaning not exponential?) at $- \infty$ eigensequences have dimension at least 1? (And why is the intersection non-trivial?)

Comment: Ahh of course they are true eigenvectors by the Fredholm theory.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of the recurrence must have at least one root on the circle, otherwise $A$ is invertible. And two subspaces of dimension greater than half the dimension of the space always intersect non-trivially.

Comment: Also I assume that $A$ is symmetric, so the roots come in pairs $z,1/z$.

Comment: The symmetry is actually not needed: the sum of the two dimensions (of sequences bounded at $\pm\infty$) is always greater than the recursion length. If you understand the argument now, what is the next level of generality you would be interested in? I believe we can go as far as an $\ell^1$ sequence for the shift invariant part and HS (or even arbitrary compact) perturbations but the right condition then is the subexponential growth, not necessarily polynomial. I don't have a proof at the moment though...

Comment: Thanks! I get it now. For the eigenvalues of $A+K$ that are not eigenvalues of $A$. They must have true eigenvectors and therefore one needs to solve the recursion exactly and the solution must be summable. For the other ones we can as you have shown also find bounded solutions to the equation.

Comment: I think this might suffice for the application I had in mind. But I wonder how general one could do it for the operator. We still do not have an analogy to the "set of spectral measure 0" that we cannot obtain as in your example with the diagonal and the closure. So I think if one wants to do a general $l^1$ sequence then one needs to have some extra condition.

Comment: It ended up not being so important for the matter. But still the discussion in this paper is somehow related to what is discussed here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.09879